# Would like a div to be visible based on true false condition

Tags: html, knockout.js

I am using knockout in my page to display other elements. I want a div to have a style display of none only if the user is an admin.

```
 <div data-bind="display: !isCurrentUserAnAdmin" class="slidingDiv" style="display:none">
```

I use knockout in my page to determine if the logged in user is an admin or not. Is this possible using data-bind on the div element?

Comment: Maybe off-topic, but even if the element is hidden, it can be easily changed with the dom inspector to make it appear. I would recommend to not render the element at all if the user is not an admin.

Comment: The element becomes visible to the admin once another condition is met. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two simple notes:

1. if you want to control an element's visibility by using knockout `visible` binding, you should not apply any style that can interfere with that, i.e. you should remove `style="display:none"` from your div
2. observables are functions which must be evaluated to get their value. When you specify an expression tha returns an `observable` in a ko binding, ko detects it and unwraps the value automatically. So, this binding would work: `visible: isCurrentUserAnAdmin`, becasue `isCurrentUserAnAdmin` is an observable. But, if the  binding expression returns something that it's not an observable, the expression is evaluated as is. So when this binding is evaluated: `visible: !isCurrentUserAnAdmin`, `visible` always becomes false, because `isCurrentUserAnAdmin` returns a `function` which is a `truish` value, that when negated by `!` becomes `false`. So you have to manually extract the value including the parenthesis, i.e. `visible: !isCurrentUserAnAdmin()`. This is the most usual error for new ko users. *NOTE: another typical error is to access a subproperty of an observable like this: `parent.childProperty`, which is undefined (an observable function doesn't contain a `childProperty`). In this case you can use either `parent().childProperty`, which returns an observable which is automatically unwrapped, or `parent().childProperty()` which directly extracts the observable value.

As to the 2nd point, you could include a computed observable in your viewmodel to avoid evaluating it on the client side. Something like this:

```
this.adminVisible = ko.computed(function() { return !isCurrentUserAnAdmin(); }, this);
```

Then your binding would be: `visible: adminVisible`. I prefer to use computed observables becasue they are less error prone, more testable, and the bindings get much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

theres no "display" binding, its a "visible" binding. so something like:

```
<div data-bind="visible: !isCurrentUserAnAdmin()" class="slidingDiv" style="display:none">
```

translates to "this div is visible if `!isCurrentUserAnAdmin()` is true

ps, in the `data-bind`, if you want the value of `isCurrentUserAnAdmin`, you need to put the `()` if its an observable

knockout documentation on visible binding: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html